# How to use same array for two different type array list in js?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two dropdown which referring one array with different labels, **From , To**

```js
var list = [{
  "label": "test1",
  "value": 1
},
{
  "label": "test2",
  "value": 2
}]

var temp = [];

list.forEach(l => {
temp.push({"value": l.value, "label": l.label})
}) 

var fromlist = temp;
var tolist = temp;

fromlist.unshift({value: null, label: "select from"});

tolist.unshift({value: null, label: "select to"});

console.log(fromlist, 'From');
console.log(tolist, 'To');
```

MY problem is fromlist, tolist both are same.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to use the `spread` operator. Saves multiple lines of code and perhaps more optimal.

```
const temp = [{"label": "test1", "value": 1},{"label": "test2","value": 2}];

const from = [{value: null, label: "select from"}, ...temp];
const to = [{value: null, label: "select to"},...temp];

console.log('From', from );
console.log('To', to );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that when you set `fromlist` equal to `temp` you are referencing your array which exists in memory (eg: the array `temp` exists in memory location `A`, fromlist now points to the memory location `A` where your array is). Thus, when you set `tolist` equal to `temp` you are pointing it to the same array that you did for `fromlist` (eg: `tolist` is also pointing to memory location `A` where your temp array is). This makes it so both your variables are referring to the same array in memory.

To resolve this issue you can spread the contents of `temp` into its own array, effectively creating a new array in memory just with the same contents.

See working example below:

```js
var list = [{"label": "test1","value": 1},{"label": "test2","value": 2}];

var temp = [];

list.forEach(l => {
  temp.push({
    "value": l.value,
    "label": l.label
  })
})

var fromlist = [...temp]; // create own unique "copy" of temp (not shared)
var tolist = [...temp]; // create own unique "copy" of temp (not shared)

fromlist.unshift({
  value: null,
  label: "select from"
});

tolist.unshift({
  value: null,
  label: "select to"
});

console.log(fromlist, 'From');
console.log(tolist, 'To');
```

Answer (score 1):

In JS arrays are passed by reference so when you are doing `var fromlist = temp; var list = temp` both `fromlist` and `tolist` refer to same array. You can use **Array Spread** or **slice** to counter this issue. So, **[...temp]** or **temp.slice()** will return a new array.

```js
var list = [{
  "label": "test1",
  "value": 1
},
{
  "label": "test2",
  "value": 2
}]

var temp = [];

list.forEach(l => {
temp.push({"value": l.value, "label": l.label})
}) 

var fromlist = [...temp]; //You can also use temp.slice()
var tolist = [...temp]; //You can also use temp.slice()

fromlist.unshift({value: null, label: "select from"});

tolist.unshift({value: null, label: "select to"});

console.log(fromlist, 'From');
console.log(tolist, 'To');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are creating `temp` variable as a copy by reference..

- Try using [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Code:

```js
const list = [{"label": "test1", "value": 1},{"label": "test2","value": 2}];
const fromlist = list.slice();
const tolist = list.slice();

fromlist.unshift({value: null, label: "select from"});
tolist.unshift({value: null, label: "select to"});

console.log('From:', fromlist);
console.log('To:', tolist);
```